# Use of ![1] syntax in GAP

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, gap

What is the use of `![1]` in GAP?

It is used in many source files.

```
gap> f:=FreeGroup( 4 );
<free group on the generators [ f1, f2, f3, f4 ]>
gap> f.1![1];
"\>"
gap> f.2![1];
"\<"
gap>
```

It is also for checking the equality of two `FreeGroup` elements (associative words) in source of GAP.
It is undocumented in GAP (seems like, as i tried or may be i don't know its method). To my understanding it seems some conversion to `unicode` characters. If possible also please mention the corresponding function in `Python`.
Thanks

Note: To those who think why i didn't ask this question on GAP forum. I must mention that "I also asked some other question of GAP on GAP forum but got no reply, it's been 1 week (i know GAP is open source), but the swiftness with which i get answers to my question on this site got me ask it here.

Comment: It is documented in 79.11 of the Reference manual. I believe that it is only intended for use by serious programmers for installing new types of objects.

Comment: @gxyd - You need Forum Subscription to be able to post there. To subscribe, please go [here](http://mail.gap-system.org/mailman/listinfo/forum). I am pretty sure there was no email from you in the Forum within the last week, so if you've just sent your email to the Forum address, it may be bounced - please check your email for bounce notifications too.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov thanks for the quick response. I again tried to subscribe to the GAP-forum, I got a mail
"An attempt was made to subscribe your address to the mailing list
forum@mail.gap-system.org.  You are already subscribed to this mailing list." ...... so on . Sorry i am not very familiar with internet forums. Do i need to do anything further?

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks yes, the documentation seems to be there. Nice getting reply from a person, whose text i am reading. :)

Comment: See also [this example of extending the system from the Circle package](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/circle/doc/chap2.html)

Comment: If you're subscribed already, please ensure that you post to the Forum from exactly the address that was used for the subscription. You may try to post it again now and I will check

Answer (score 2):

For an object stored internally in the format of a list, `A![1]` accesses the internal storage (in component 1 etc.) of this object.
Groups (such as the free group in you example) are not stored in this format, so the data in your example is not really meaningful but the equivalent of a random `Peek` in BASIC. The representation as unicode is a side effect of having to represent somewhat random bytes.

(For objects, such a groups, that are stored based on the record format, `A!.componentname` is an analog construct.)

In general objects have proper functions to access their internal data structures. So unless you are working with very low level code (and know these internal data structures) there is no reason to use the ! operator.

Comment: For example, the [Circle package manual](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/circle/doc/chap2.html) has the following text explaining why is better to avoid "!" being called by the end user: _"We need to avoid the usage of "!" operator, which, in general, is not recommended to the user (for example, if GAP developers will change the internal representation of some object, all GAP functions that deal with it must be adjusted appropriately, while if the user's code had direct access to that representation via "!", an error may occur)."_